# TYPO3 - Change order of elements within image element

Tags: image, element, typo3

I have a default text/image element on a TYPO3 page and the content inside is in this order:

1. title
2. image
3. text

I need this order:

1. image
2. title
3. text

I've been trying to modify the tt_content std.header object within my typoscript but it is not working properly.

Does anyone know an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into: `/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt`

Search for: `CType: image` (line ~650), then copy it whole into your typoscript template, purge `tt_content.image.10` (it's header) and try to place `lib.stdheader` in required place in `tt_content.image.20`... just a concept, I did something similar years ago and don't remember details...

Other option is using CSS/JS for changing the order, maybe it will be easier ?

Answer (score 1):

```
tt_content.textpic {
# remove default header
    10 >
    20 = < tt_content.image.20                
    20 {
        layout = TEXT
        layout.value = <div class="your-classes###CLASSES###">###IMAGES###</div>###TEXT###

# insert the header as part of text
        text.15 = < lib.stdheader 
        text.20 = < tt_content.text.20
        text.wrap >
    }
}
```